# Appending 2-D numpy array to 3-D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a loop that creates a new (2, 3) array every time. I want to append these arrays together to create a new array 3-D array, I think an example explains what I want to do best. Say I have an array `arr1 = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])` and an array `arr2 = array([[11, 22, 33], [44, 55, 66]])`. I want to get a new array by "adding the arrays" so something like `arr3 = np.array([[[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33]], [[4,44], [5,55], [6,66]]])`. In practice this would look something like:

```
import numpy as np

n_samples = 10
total_arr = np.empty([2, 3, n_samples])

for i in range(n_samples):
   arr = np.random.rand(2,3)
   total_arr.append(arr) #This is the step I don't know what do do with

print(total_arr.shape)
>>> (2, 3, 10) #Where 10 is whatever n_samples is
```

My current method is to cast `total_arr` to a list with `total_lst = total_arr.tolist()` and append each `arr[i,j]` to the lists in `total_lst` with a for loop. So something like `total_list[i][j].append(arr[i,j])` but this is taking much too long, is there a numpy solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [179]: arr1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]); arr2 = np.array([[11, 22, 33], [44, 55, 66]])                
In [180]: arr1                                                                                                  
Out[180]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [181]: arr2                                                                                                  
Out[181]: 
array([[11, 22, 33],
       [44, 55, 66]])
```

`np.stack` can join a list of arrays along a new axis.  The default is to act like `np.array([arr1, arr2])`, but it looks like you want a new last axis:

```
In [182]: np.stack([arr1, arr2], axis=2)                                                                        
Out[182]: 
array([[[ 1, 11],
        [ 2, 22],
        [ 3, 33]],

       [[ 4, 44],
        [ 5, 55],
        [ 6, 66]]])
```

In general, collecting the arrays in a list and doing one 'join' at the end is best.  Trying to the array join iterative is slower, and harder to do right.

Alternatively you can create an array of the right target size, and assign elements/blocks.

===

New first axis example:

```
In [183]: np.stack([arr1, arr2])                                                                                
Out[183]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[11, 22, 33],
        [44, 55, 66]]])
In [184]: np.stack([arr1, arr2]).transpose(1,2,0)                                                               
Out[184]: 
array([[[ 1, 11],
        [ 2, 22],
        [ 3, 33]],

       [[ 4, 44],
        [ 5, 55],
        [ 6, 66]]])
```